# Connecting to Server Sent Events in production environment (NestJS/Angular)

Tags: angular, nestjs, server-sent-events

I have a NestJS/Angular application that uses SSE to push data to the frontend.

I have a problem with the connection to the `EventSource` the request that goes from the frontend to connect to the SSE is always pending.

Locally everything works fine but when I deploy the application nothing works, I checked all my configuration/CORS and nothing seems to change.

```js
  // backend
  // event.controller.ts
@Controller('event')
export class EventController {
  // [...] class initialization with constructor
  @Sse('sse/:id')
  @Header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  @Header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream')
  @Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  @Header('Connection', 'keep alive')
  @Header('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no')
  sse(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Req() req: Request
  ): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return this.service.subscribeToTopicUpdate(id)
  }
}
```

```js
  // frontend
  // sse.service.ts
  getEventSourceFrom(eventId: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(`${environment.baseUrl}/event/sse/${eventId}`);
  }
```

In my network console, the request is always pending and never resolved.

[network console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPNqS.png)

[request headers img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcIFD.png)

I added all the requested headers in my request by nothing changes.

I also tried deploying the frontend and backend on different domains by configuring CORS.

Same things using a REST Client like Postman.

Comment: Have you fixed this yet?

Comment: I have this same exact issue. Would be interested to hear if you found a solution.